# How to create a site template and add fields to list automatically. For detailed question. Please find below

Tags: custom-list, site-template

I need to first create a site template which consist of project name, description, attachments and appointment fields. Then automatically add few of their fields to the project management list.

How can I do above things like creating sie template and then automatically add few contains like project name, description to the list.

Please help me out. Sharepoint is completely new for me. I am using SharePoint 365.
Your help is appreciated.

Comment: how do you want to create it? do you have an existing site which contains all these fields and list?

Comment: No, I need to create a new site template having project name, description and document library then every time the end-user clicks on create a new site then that template should get open and after saving the site, project name, description and link should automatically get added to the one list( which needs to be created)

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately a bit complex these days. SharePoint used to have a "save site as template" feature, where we could configure a site how we wanted, including lists, custom fields, etc., and even documents and list items. It was one mouse click to create the template, and then we could just specify we wanted to use the template when creating any new subsite. This is still available in SharePoint online,but it only works with classic, non-publishing sites, where the user script feature is enabled. Assuming you're working with new "modern" sites, we have "site designs" instead.

The end result of a site design is quite nice: a user clicks to create a new site, they select which site design (or template) they want to use from a drop-down, and the site gets created with all the lists, libraries, custom fields, etc., that you want. Getting there is...not so nice. you need to create a json file that has all the additional pieces you want, like the lists and fields. Again, the end result is good, but it takes somewhat of a developer skill set to get it operational. The docs for this are [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview).

Other options include powershell, especially with the [PNP PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps) libraries, as well as 3rd party tools.